# Wordpress add_filter use variable

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using Awesome Support and I want to add a filter to manually assign the agent to answer the tickets.

This is the funcition:

```
function wpas_find_agent( $ticket_id = false ) {

    if ( defined( 'WPAS_DISABLE_AUTO_ASSIGN' ) && true === WPAS_DISABLE_AUTO_ASSIGN ) {
        return apply_filters( 'wpas_find_available_agent', wpas_get_option( 'assignee_default' ), $ticket_id );
    }

    $users = shuffle_assoc( wpas_get_users( apply_filters( 'wpas_find_agent_get_users_args', array( 'cap' => 'edit_ticket' ) ) ) );
    $agent = array();

    foreach ( $users->members as $user ) {

        $wpas_agent = new WPAS_Member_Agent( $user );

        /**
         * Make sure the user really is an agent and that he can currently be assigned
         */
        if ( true !== $wpas_agent->is_agent() || false === $wpas_agent->can_be_assigned() ) {
            continue;
        }

        $count = $wpas_agent->open_tickets(); // Total number of open tickets for this agent

        if ( empty( $agent ) ) {
            $agent = array(
                'tickets' => $count,
                'user_id' => $user->ID,
            );
        } else {

            if ( $count < $agent['tickets'] ) {
                $agent = array(
                    'tickets' => $count,
                    'user_id' => $user->ID,
                );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( is_array( $agent ) && isset( $agent['user_id'] ) ) {
        $agent_id = $agent['user_id'];
    } else {

        $default_id = wpas_get_option( 'assignee_default', 1 );

        if ( empty( $default_id ) ) {
            $default_id = 1;
        }

        $agent_id = $default_id;

    }

    return apply_filters( 'wpas_find_available_agent', (int) $agent_id, $ticket_id );

}
```

And this is the filter I want to add:

```
add_filter('wpas_find_available_agent', 'asignar_agente', 10, 2);
function asignar_agente($agent_id){
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $ticket_id, 'department', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    if($term_list[0] == 34){
        $agent_id = 2;
    }else{
        $agent_id = 3;
    }

    return $agent_id;
}
```

How can I pass the $ticket_id variable to the filter to use it?

I need this variable because I need to know the term (department taxonomy) of the ticket is being submitted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `$ticket_id` when you call `apply_filters('wpas_find_available_agent'....);` you will be able to get the `$ticket_id` if you change your filter function to.

```
function asignar_agente($agent_id, $ticket_id){  <--- just add this parameter here
...
}
```

this is possible since you pass the parameter in `apply_filters` and you say `add_filter('wpas_find_available_agent', 'asignar_agente', 10, 2);` with emphasis on the last parameter with the value 2, that means your filter function will be able to receive 2 parameters.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I added the $ticket_id variable but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you try to debug what value `$ticket_id` has when the code reaches your filter function `asignar_agente`? From the main function `wpas_find_agent()` the `$ticket_id` could be false (default when not provided). The problem may be at the line `$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $ticket_id, 'department', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );` since we don't know the value of `$ticket_id` and what it is supposed to be.

Comment: I ended up editing directly the plugin, I don't know if there is a way to override the function declared by a plugin in my functions.php.